# Navigation Border

Tags: html, css, navigation, border

So my navigation links currently have a border to the left, so I was wondering if there would be a way to make it so there's no border on the first one (makes it uneven). Look at the image: [Screenshot](http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/7640/0d0b92080e5146ccbbc5e7e.png)

I tried making a class: .noborder {border:0;} then adding  but it didn't work

Thanks for the help

Comment: If your <a> element is inside <li> element try to put that .noborder class inside <li> element. Or float:left... We are just imagine what is structure of that menu, and guessing so please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must set **margin:0;**. It would be easier to help by adding the relating css to your post.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy fix, using border: 0; will work you obviously just haven't assigned it to the correct element.

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="nodec"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Websites</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

#nav ul li {
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}

.nodec {
    border-left: 0px;
}
```

Add in all your other formatting (padding, colour, margins) and it'll work just fine. One other thing though: have a read up on website colour schemas, just google it and you'll find many articles on the subject. Also check out Adobe Color Kuler (http://kuler.adobe.com/).  It's something you may find helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The class probably doesn't work because it's just that, a class.
You can ether put !important after the value: `.noborder {border:0 !important;}`
Or make it more precise for example:  `.noborder > a {border:0;}`
Depending on your html, for a better answer i would recommend you to submit both your html and css.

Comment: Using !important for a specificity issue is terrible advice; you are much better off dealing with the issue than implementing a work-around that can cause further problems down the road.

Comment: well, it is the only solution that is guaranteed to work if he doesn't post his html and css. No need to downvote that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond to your comment. Saying that your solution is the only one that will work when you don't know what you need to be fixing doesn't make it right. Waiting for all the information would be the correct thing to do.

Comment: ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin: auto;
  padding:0;
  width:525px;
 }

 ul li {
  display:inline;
 }
 
 ul li a {
  text-decoration:none;
  width:100px;
  background:#485e49;
  color:#eee;
  height: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
 }
 
 ul li a {
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:20px 0;
  width:100px;
  background:#485e49;
  color:#eee;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  border-left:1px solid #fff;
 }

Comment: <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Websites</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Designs</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Previews</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>